# it is possible to use Firebase-Cloud-Messaging

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send SMS or make phone calls using FCM

I want to develop SOS alert feature in my application , through my research for sending notifications FCM is better and no cost. but I had a doubt it supports SMS, voice calls USING fire base real-time database how?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can send SMS or make a phone call with (just) Firebase Cloud Messaging, not with (just) Firebase Realtime Database.

You will need to use a service that supports the specific functionality you need. Recommending a service is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but a search for [API to send SMS](https://www.google.com/search?q=api+to+send+sms&oq=API+to+send+SMS) would be a good place to start.